# How to handle SSL certificate handshake failure error using karate dsl?

Tags: dsl, karate

I am validating my SSL algorithm by setting the configure ssl = 'TLSv1.2' which gives me 200 response code.

But , if the algirithm is not TLSv1.2, it just throws a raw error with no response code like this :

14:53:26.025 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake, http call failed after 22 milliseconds for URL: https://XXXX.com.au/event/countryTLSV11/v1/countries
14:53:26.026 http request failed: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Is there any way to handle this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I think you are wasting time on a negative test that will not give you much benefit. Positive tests should be good enough.

But if you insist, use a second feature to do the HTTP request. Then you can handle the error in JavaScript:

```
* eval try { karate.call('my.feature') } catch(e) { karate.log('failed:', e) }
```

Comment: It's a requirement. I can't skip negative tests. The only problem is this response does not give any response code for failure which is blocking me. Thanks Anyways . I will try it with a second feature.

Comment: @SnehaShukla whatever you say. personally I think it is a stupid requirement :)

Comment: @PeterThomas: Although, this is stupid, I tried this and I am able to make by test pass by simple js call in feature. But exception is generic karate exception, is there a way to get the actual exception being thrown??

Comment: @shrik18 I am not sure. you are welcome to dig into the code and contribute more if needed

Comment: I will raise an issue and do that.